# Why this hibernate template bulkUpdate doesn't work

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring

Oracle 10g, Hibernate 3.4

This update (based on `long user.userId` value) is done correctly:

```
getHibernateTemplate().bulkUpdate("update Address address set address.preferred = 1 where address.user.userId = ?", 1l);
```

This one (based on `String user.language` value) throws an exception `ORA-00971: missing SET keyword`:

```
getHibernateTemplate().bulkUpdate("update Address address set address.preferred = 1 where address.user.language = ?", "en");
```

Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/batch.html#batch-direct) says:

> - No joins, either implicit or explicit, can be specified in a bulk HQL query. Sub-queries can be used in the where-clause, where the subqueries themselves may contain joins.

So, you need to replace implicit join with the equivalent subquery:

```
getHibernateTemplate().bulkUpdate(
   "update Address address set address.preferred = 1 " +
   "where address.user in (select u from User u where u.language = ?)",
   "en");
```