# HibernateTemplate bulkUpdate using IN - clause

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, bulkupdate

How to perform bulkUpdate operation using hibernateTemplate. The following code throws

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond
>   number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal
>   parameters are 1-based! Position: 2

```
HibernateTemplate.bulkUpdate("update Address address set address.city = 'Oakland' where address.user in (:users)", users);
```

How to achieve this batch update operation by passing list of users as a parameter???

Comment: Can you try.. HibernateTemplate.bulkUpdate("update Address address set address.city = 'Oakland' where address.user in (?)", users);

Comment: I have tried this also, it  throws "    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of user.id; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter user.id"

Comment: Ohh that looks like your POJO is not proper one. Check getter setter for your User Pojo with field id. But I think uptil now you might got your answer.

Comment: Thanks Ketan for your reply. Still am stuck with this problem.. I didn't get answer yet :( Kindly help how do I solve this problem???

Comment: Yup. As I mentioned earlier it looks like your POJO is not proper one. Check getter setter for your User Pojo with field id.

Answer (score 0):

This question is possible duplicate of [why-this-hibernate-template-bulkupdate-doesnt-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368522/why-this-hibernate-template-bulkupdate-doesnt-work.)

Answer in above question may solve this issue. Hope it helps. Happy Learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Its very very strange, I searched alot and also could not find solution, the doc says that it is binding number of values to "?" parameters in the query string but when I provide list as parameter - it is not binding for IN clause as string. So I did a workaround - provided parameters as String :

```
StringBuilder inClauseparams = new StringBuilder("(");
    for (int i = 0; i < notificationIDs.size(); i++) {
        inClauseparams.append(""+notificationIDs.get(i));
        if( i != notificationIDs.size()-1 )
            inClauseparams.append(",");
        else
            inClauseparams.append(")");
    }
    hibernateTemplate.bulkUpdate("update Notification set isSeen = true where id in "+inClauseparams.toString());
```